# not able to access the maven spring boot application running in docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile, portforwarding, docker-container

I have created a docker file from maven spring boot application and created a docker image and pushed it to my docker registry.

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/spring-boot-lazy-init-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar spring-boot-lazy-init-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "spring-boot-lazy-init-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

this is the content what I have written inside docker file and created a docker image. I have changed the tag and pushed it to my docker hub repository which I will use for deployment purpose in Kubernetes cluster but before that I have used this docker image for testing purpose. I have used this docker image to run a container and I have also done the port forwarding as application was running on 8080 port by default.

```
ubuntu@dockerimage-vm:~/spring-boot-lazy-init-example$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY                 TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
96963/spring-boot-new      v1                  1e4a8aab28f8        3 days ago          526MB
96963/docker-spring-boot   v1                  2f2a3b1c23e8        8 days ago          526MB
docker-spring-boot-new     latest              2f2a3b1c23e8        8 days ago          526MB
openjdk                    8                   f8146facf376        2 weeks ago         488MB

ubuntu@dockerimage-vm:~$ sudo docker run -it 96963/spring-boot-new:v1 -p 8085:8080

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v2.2.0.M1)

2020-01-17 11:38:21.417  INFO 1 --- [           main] t.l.SpringBootLazyInitExampleApplication : Starting SpringBootLazyInitExampleApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on 03ab2d24c370 with PID 1 (/spring-boot-lazy-init-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /)
2020-01-17 11:38:21.426  INFO 1 --- [           main] t.l.SpringBootLazyInitExampleApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-01-17 11:38:23.355  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-01-17 11:38:23.451  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 67ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2020-01-17 11:38:24.391  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cf2fe8c5] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-01-17 11:38:25.625  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-01-17 11:38:26.191  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-01-17 11:38:26.192  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
2020-01-17 11:38:26.258  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2020-01-17 11:38:26.486  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-01-17 11:38:26.489  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4929 ms
2020-01-17 11:38:27.532  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-01-17 11:38:28.182  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-01-17 11:38:28.398  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2020-01-17 11:38:28.627  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.0.Final}
2020-01-17 11:38:28.640  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-01-17 11:38:29.171  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-01-17 11:38:29.438  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-01-17 11:38:30.312  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@1b11171f'
2020-01-17 11:38:30.337  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-01-17 11:38:30.339  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-01-17 11:38:30.694  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-01-17 11:38:30.701  INFO 1 --- [           main] t.l.SpringBootLazyInitExampleApplication : Started SpringBootLazyInitExampleApplication in 10.338 seconds (JVM running for 11.976)
2020-01-17 12:08:38.990  WARN 1 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=28m10s615ms885µs724ns)
```

I have also tried to run the application from local machine and I am able to reach the url 
[image]

[image]

but while I am trying to reach the application which is running inside docker container I am not able to reach. I am accessing that from 192.168.64.3:8085/lazy, (8085 because I have done the port forwarding at that port).

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Using screenshots for code and command output is a bad practice: They are much less readable than standard text, no-one can copy paste them (for tests or search) and they cannot be indexed by search engines (SO internal or external). Can you please edit your question and replace those code/output screenshots with formatted code blocks ? Thank you.

Comment: `-p 8085:8080` is mapping port 8085 of localhost (i.e. the host running docker daemon) to port 8080 on the docker container. You are exposing in your dockerfile port 8085 on the container. Can you please double check and update if needed which port your application is supposed to use on the container ?

Comment: @Zeitounator hey thanks and I have changed the particular screenshots with code blocks which were required and the previous docker file was wrong and I have also updated the same here. I am exposing 8080 port on docker container and used the same for port forwarding. I have made the changes in docker file.

Comment: it should work as long as your docker is running on 192.168.64.3 and 192.168.64.3 is your Host IP. Please check ...